# How can I make a symmetrical navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have this navbar:

[image]

There is too much space at the left and I want the same space at the left and at the right. I have this code:

```
 <!--html-->
         <nav>
           <ul>
            <li>Tutorials</li>
            <li>News</li>
           </ul>
          </nav>
```

```
/*css*/
nav{
background-color: rgb(255, 86, 86);
margin: auto;   
height: 50px;
padding: 10px;
width: fit-content;
margin: auto;
}
nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're butting heads with the browser defaults.

It's common to [reset the browser's default padding/margin for all elements to zero](https://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/) because some elements (like ul and li) can have some default margin/padding. Also, you didn't specify the `list-style-type` of the list to be `none`, which I assume means the unordered list defaults to bullets, a result you don't want.

Here's what I would personally do to accomplish what you're looking for, excluding colors:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This puts a 10px space around all of the items, and then a 10px space between each of them. It also forces the list to display horizontally without needing to inline the list items. The [CSS Tricks guide to flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be helpful to you.

There's many right answers here, so try to have fun with it and pick the method that feels the best to you.